# Getting random object from object array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to get a different object every iteration of the loop. Im getting the object from an array of objects defined in another method and used in this one, but the object (book) remains unchanged.
the for each loop is followed by other statements and working properly hence not related.

```
public static String [] runSimulation(LibraryBook [] bookStock, int numberOFevents){
    Random rnd = new Random();
    String [] output = new String [numberOFevents];
    int a = rnd.nextInt(100);
    int n = LibraryBook.getBooks();
    int c = rnd.nextInt(1);
    int random = rnd.nextInt(n-1);
    //for (int index=0; index<numberOFevents; index++) {
    int i=0;
    for (LibraryBook book : bookStock ){
        i++;
        book = bookStock[random];
        if (book.getLibraryClass() == null) {
            book.setLibraryClass("QA" + a ); 
            output[i] += (i + book.getLibraryClass()+ "BOOK IS CLASSIFIED");
        }
        else if (book.getLibraryClass() != null && 
            "REFERENCE_ONLY".equals(book.getBookStatus())){
            output[i] += (i + book.getLibraryClass() + "REFERENCE ONLY BOOK");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not changing random every time in the loop. Your code should look like this:

```
    int random;
    int i=0;
    for (LibraryBook book : bookStock ){
        i++;
        random = rnd.nextInt(n-1); // sets a new value in every loop
        book = bookStock[random];
```

Comment: damn that was such a silly mistake haha, thanks mate